Copy-pasting a part of LGPL-licensed file into Python library
I want to copy a part of LGPLv3-licensed file into a Python library. Said file: https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/blob/master/data/SMARTS_InteLigand.txt. I want to copy SMARTS patterns (chemical structure definitions) contained there, but without comments, additional information etc., only the list of structure definitions. It will be a Python list of strings. The resulting library will be MIT-licenced.

Do I have to make anything LGPL? I.e. are a list of publicly available chemical definitions covered by copyright? I know that they can be patented, but this is a whole other thing, if I understand correctly.

If I copy only a heavily edited part of a file (only partial definitions, without comments etc.) into a Python script, which is distributed along the rest of the library, do I have to distribute that script under LGPL?

How would that affect the rest of the library? For example, if only a single class in a single script would contain that material, does the whole library need to be LGPL-licensed?



I wanted to note that the file in question does not say which LGPL version. It simply says the "Lesser General Public License (LGPL license)". But based on the 2005 date, I think it is a mistake to assume that LGPLv3 was intended, since the LGPLv3 was first published in 2007.


How would that affect the rest of the library? For example, if only a single class in a single script would contain that material, does the whole library need to be LGPL-licensed?

The LGPL license is a copyleft license with "library scope". The copyleft nature means that once something is licensed under the LGPL, it needs to remain under that license (or the GPL). With the term "library scope", I mean that if a part of a library is under the LGPL, then the entire library needs to be under the LGPL, but applications linking to the library are free in their license choice.
So, even if you copied just a single LGPL-licensed class into a library, then you must license the entire library under the LGPL.

If I copy only a heavily edited part of a file (only partial definitions, without comments etc.) into a Python script, which is distributed along the rest of the library, do I have to distribute that script under LGPL?

Yes. Even if you copied just a single line, if it derives from LGPL code, it needs to remain under the LGPL.

Do I have to make anything LGPL? I.e. are a list of publicly available chemical definitions covered by copyright? I know that they can be patented, but this is a whole other thing, if I understand correctly.

In principle, you need to license your entire library under the LGPL.
With the list of chemical definitions, there might be a loophole. If the list does not contain any creativity at all, not in the selections of the chemical compounds included nor in the notation used to describe the definitions, then it can be argued that it is a list of mere facts that isn't subject to copyright protection. In that case, you don't need a license to use the list of facts.

Another option to avoid having to release your library under the LGPL is to write the library such that it reads the required data from an external file, where your reading code is able to parse the SMARTS_InteLigand.txt file.
If you provide for a way for the user to supply their own file (possibly even by overwriting the file you provided), you can provide the SMARTS_InteLigand.txt file as a default data source. This file would have to remain under the LGPL license, but the rest of your library can be licensed in any way you like.

I see no permission in LGPLv3 to relicense under AGPL, only under GPL.  Have I missed something?  Other than that, though, +1 from me.

One more question to make sure - if I copy the entire file itself, and read from it at runtime, it does not affect the license of the library then, right? Since as far as I understand, this would be equivalent to using an external library. Or does this still require LGPL for the whole library, since I distribute that single file? Obviously, that single file would be still under LGPL.

@qalis, see my edit.

@BartvanIngenSchenau great, thanks for the explanation! This seems like a way to go then.

Note that the comment in this file is from 2005 (before publication of the LGPLv3), so I think the intention was to license this file under LGPLv2.1, although it does not say so explicitly, and it seems someone forgot to attach the license terms themselves for that file. In LGPLv2.1, the "library" is defined as "a collection of software functions and/or data prepared so as to be conveniently linked with application programs".

@Brandin, the (L|A)GPL licenses state that if the copyright holder doesn't specify a license version, then the recipient can choose any version of that license ever published by the FSF. The file in question does not state a version of the LGPL, so interpreting that as either LGPLv2.1 or LGPLv3 is equally valid.

You don't even need to read the text file. Follow the intended idea to turn the file into Python code, but make that Python code a stand-alone Python module (e.g. SMARTS_InteLigand.py). Now make that part LGPL. Your own library can remain MIT, it just has a dependency on the LGPL library.

@MSalters what about distribution then? As far as I understand, I would have to separately distribute the LGPL-library, and add it as an external dependency for MIT one. Or can I have purely MIT library and a single Python script inside it with another license? Because the second one sounds like a huge loophole - I could always say that only a single file is LGPL (and modify, copy-paste, whatever in that single file), all the rest is MIT, and be done. This doesn't sound quite right.

The second option is indeed not possible, as you expect.

"Even if you copied just a single line" Such a small amount might fall under the fair use exception to copyright protection.

@Barmar the fair use exception has more criteria to it than just the size.

It will also fall under the "effect on potential market" factor. And if the line is something trivial like a = a + 1, there's probably not enough creativity for it to be even copyrighted -- larger portions of the library are copyrightable because there's creativity in the order and organization.
